# How to attach .onReceive(NotificationCenter) handler to iOS application object

Tags: swiftui, nsnotificationcenter

I'm starting to play with SwiftUI. I found code that allows me to attach an `onReceive()` handler to a view object, set up to respond to `NotificationCenter` messages like `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification`.

However, I want to make the same code-base build iOS and Mac apps. I added a MacOS target to my project and got the ContentView working on both platforms. I'd rather not add a bunch of `#if os(macOS)` or `#if os(iOS)` conditionally compiled code to my `ContentView`.

The iOS target template creates a SwiftUI App object:

```
@main
struct SwiftUI_CounterButtonApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like the Mac target does not have an App object like that.

I'd like to put my code that handles will Enter Foreground notifications at the app level rather than the ContentView level.

Is it possible to add an `onReceive()` handler to the iOS `App` object?

And what would the equivalent be for the Mac OS target? All I see in the Mac OS target is Swift code that creates and installs my ContentView. I don't see SwiftUI code in the MacOS target.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same target for both iOS and macOS. Just check `macOS` in the `General` -> `Deployment Info` section.

Then you can use the same code for both platforms:

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
                    print("active")
                }
        }
    }
}
```